# Limiting distribution of $W_n = Z_n/n^2$ where $Z_n\sim \chi^{2}(n).$ using pdfs

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, chi-squared

The goal is to find the limiting distribution of $W_n = Z_n/n^2$ where $Z_n\sim \chi^{2}(n).$

I know from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/80055/256707) answer that $W_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution. I am trying to get this answer using CDFs.

$F_{W_n}(w)=P(\dfrac{Z_n}{n^2}\leq w)=P(Z_n\leq n^2w)=F_{Z_n}(n^2w)$

hence, differentiating partially with respect to $w$ we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{W_n}(w)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2n\cdot f_{Z_n}(n^2w)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2n\cdot \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}n^2w}\cdot (\frac{1}{2}\cdot n^2w)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$

I don't know what to do after this.
I know that   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{W_n}(w)$ has to be a probability mass function, but the above method will not give a probability mass function for sure. So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You misread the answer.

Comment: thanks for that, fixed it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406125/limiting-distribution-of-w-n-z-n-n2-where-z-n-sim-chi2n?rq=1

Comment: @d.k.o. I understand the approach in that question(whose link you provided). what i do not understand is why my approach does not work

Comment: Check out this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437946/a-s-convergence-of-densities-implies-convergence-in-distribution) (convergence of densities vs. weak convergence).

Comment: @d.k.o. so my approach does not work because convergence in distribution does not imply convergence in pmf/pdf?

Comment: Not always (you need some condition on the sequence of pdfs). The converse is, however, true. You may work with cdfs, instead, showing that $F_{W_n}(w)$ converges to $1$ for $w>0$. However, it is easier to work with ch.f's in this case.